# php foreach loop return only last element?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have an app that must get some data from a provider.
For this I have some data in db and load it through model in costume MVC model and try to fetch all data in array (assoc) and it works totally true.

at end I want to collect all in to the list and pass the list from class to controller.

I've done it before for the other parameter here in this class but now when I want to collect it it return just last record!

here is the code:

```
    public function getDetails()
{

    $provider = [];

    $provider['local']['images'] = $this->loadModel('images')->getProviderImages($this->provider_id);
    $provider['local']['applications'] = $this->loadModel('images')->getProviderApplications($this->provider_id);
    $provider['local']['plans'] = $this->loadModel('plans')->getProviderPlans($this->provider_id);
    $provider['local']['dataCenters'] = $this->loadModel('regions')->getProviderRegions($this->provider_id);
    $provider['local']['snapshots'] = $this->loadModel('snapshots')->getProviderSnapshots($this->provider_id);

    try {
        $provider['remote']['images'] = $this->getImages()->images;
        $provider['remote']['plans'] = $this->getPlans()->plans;
        $provider['remote']['dataCenters'] = $this->getDataCenters()->data_centers;

        if (!$provider['remote']['images'] || !$provider['remote']['plans'] || !$provider['remote']['dataCenters']) {
            throw new Exception ("Can't connect to provider. creating provider details array failed!");
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        log_error($e);

        return false;
    }
    /***********/


    $temp = [];
    foreach ($provider['local']['images'] as $key => $image) {
        foreach ($provider['remote']['images'] as $r_key => $r_image) {
            if ($image['is_active'] == true) {
//                                r($r_image);

if ($image['slug'] == $r_image['slug']) {
                    $temp['images'][$image['os_name']]['name'] = $image['name'];
                    $version = $image['os_version'];
                    $version .= (!empty($image['os_architecture'])) ? '-' . $image['os_architecture'] : '';
                    $temp['images'][$image['os_name']]['versions'][$version] = $image;
                    $temp['images'][$image['os_name']]['versions'][$version]['dataCenters'] = $r_image['regions'];

                    if ($image['image_id'] != $r_image['id']) {
                        $this->loadModel('images')->updateImageID($this->provider_id, $image['slug'], $r_image['id']);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }//die(r($temp));
    foreach ($provider['local']['snapshots'] as $key => $snapshot) {
        foreach ($provider['remote']['images'] as $r_key => $r_image) {
            if ($snapshot['snapshot_id'] == $r_image['id']) {

                $temp['snapshots'][$r_image['distribution']] = $r_image;
                $temp['snapshots'][$r_image['distribution']]['service_provider'] = $snapshot['service_provider_id'];
                $temp['snapshots'][$r_image['distribution']]['os_name'] = strtolower($r_image['distribution']);

                break;
            }
        }
    }//die(r($temp));





       foreach ($provider['local']['applications'] as $key => $app) {
            foreach ($provider['remote']['images'] as $r_key => $r_image) {
                if ($app['is_active'] == true) {

//                r($r_image);
                    //echo "{$image['image_id']} == {$r_image->id} | ";
                    if (empty($r_image['slug'])) {
                        if ($app['image_id'] == $r_image['id']) {
                            $temp['applications'][$app['app_name']]['name'] = $app['name'];
                            $temp['applications'][$app['app_name']]['os'][$app['os_name']][$app['os_version'] . '-' . $app['os_architecture']] = $app;
                            $temp['applications'][$app['app_name']]['os'][$app['os_name']][$app['os_version'] . '-' . $app['os_architecture']]['dataCenters'] = $r_image['regions'];
                            break;
                        }
                    } elseif ($app['slug'] == $r_image['slug']) {
                        $temp['applications'][$app['app_name']]['name'] = $app['name'];
                    $temp['applications'][$app['app_name']]['os'][$app['os_name']][$app['os_version'] . '-' . $app['os_architecture']] = $app;
                    $temp['applications'][$app['app_name']]['os'][$app['os_name']][$app['os_version'] . '-' . $app['os_architecture']]['dataCenters'] = $r_image['regions'];

                    if ($app['image_id'] != $r_image['id']) {
                        $this->loadModel('images')->updateImageID($this->provider_id, $app['slug'], $r_image['id']);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }//die();


    foreach ($provider['local']['plans'] as $key => $plan) {
        foreach ($provider['remote']['plans'] as $r_key => $r_plan) {
            //echo "{$plan['slug']} == {$r_plan->slug} | ";
            if ($plan['slug'] == $r_plan['slug'] && $r_plan['available']) {
                $temp['plans'][$plan['slug']] = $plan;
                $temp['plans'][$plan['slug']]['dataCenters'] = $r_plan['regions'];

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // sort by plan's price
    uasort($temp['plans'], function ($a, $b) {
        return $a['hourly_price'] > $b['hourly_price'];
    });

    foreach ($provider['local']['dataCenters'] as $key => $dc) {
        foreach ($provider['remote']['dataCenters'] as $r_key => $r_dc) {
            //echo "{$dc['slug']} == {$r_dc->slug} | ";
            if ($dc['slug'] == $r_dc['slug'] && $r_dc['available']) {
                $temp['dataCenters'][$dc['country']][$dc['city']][$dc['slug']] = $dc;
                $temp['dataCenters'][$dc['country']][$dc['city']][$dc['slug']]['plans'] = $r_dc['sizes'];
                $temp['features'][$dc['slug']] = $r_dc['features'];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $temp;
}
```

My problem is in these lines:

```
>         foreach ($provider['local']['snapshots'] as $key => $snapshot) {
>            foreach ($provider['remote']['images'] as $r_key => $r_image) {
>                if ($snapshot['snapshot_id'] == $r_image['id']) {
>
>                   $temp['snapshots'][$r_image['distribution']] = $r_image;
>                    $temp['snapshots'][$r_image['distribution']]['service_provider'] = $snapshot['service_provider_id'];
>                    $temp['snapshots'][$r_image['distribution']]['os_name'] = strtolower($r_image['distribution']);
>
>                    break;
>                }
>            }
>        }
```

Comment: shouldn't be here `$temp['snapshots'][$r_image['distribution']] = $r_image;` be some kind of identification for the current 'snapshot'? You're overwriting the same snapshot.

Comment: good idea, let me check it!

Comment: look but I want to categorize with name of distribution and it's just become an index in list! is it true?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the awnser, I schuould use some variable as an index, like this:

```
$temp['snapshots'][$snapshot['id']] = $r_image;
```

and it works,